# Why do so many packages need to be upgraded when I only specify one to apt-get

Tags: apt, pip

I use ALT Linux 6, and I need to launch a Python 3 script which uses OpenGL and openCV, I realized that pip is absent in my Python installation which is already dumb), then somehow I figured that pip under Linux is called python-module-pip, so I write in terminal

```
apt-get install python-module-pip
```

And I get that 251 packages will be upgraded, 215 new installed, 776 removed, 62 MB downloaded, 2550 MB freed. Why is that so difficult to just install 1 package?

I haven't mentioned that I am now enforced to use Firefox 17.0 because I have 12 GB free disk space on my Linux partition, but it is not enough to upgrade Firefox when it also tries to pull many other packages, effectively upgrading the whole OS, the same as I physically cannot do an upgrade to ALT Linux 8.0 because there is not enough disk space to unpack all packages.

Comment: It sounds like you have a pending transaction in apt from a previous failed action. You likely get the same result with `apt-get install -f`

Comment: Anyway the important part is "776 removed". Perhaps mixed repositories creating conflicts?

Comment: 1. most or all of the python modules you want are probably already packaged - it's always better to install the packaged version than to risk breaking your system with pip.  2. if you're running out of space on / but have free disk space on other partitions, you can move and symlink `/var/cache/apt/archives` to, the fs with free space.  e.g., if /home has lots of free space, use `/home/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Answer (score 3):

It saves labor and time when common code can be factored out into a library.  The functions a library contains can be tested independently of any client program and reused in many programs without duplicating the development time and effort.

So it’s not uncommon for major things like Python to have many dependencies.  You’ll see lots of dependencies for any major program like X11, gcc, perl, etc.

Since programming languages can be asked to do many things, it’s not uncommon for them to depend on many libraries either.

Comment: I would ad that if you haven't update your system in a while, your current repo probably knows the last version of the package and imply to upgrade and install a lot of missing package because upgrade hasn't been installe for a long time.